# AWS SimpleDB - how to create an offset to address default result limit of 100

Tags: amazon-simpledb

AWS SimpleDB has a default result limit of 100 and I am trying to get the last 20 records from my database.  Their online help states: "The next token returned by count(*) and select are interchangeable as long as the where and order by clauses match. For example, if you want to return the 200 items after the first 10,000 (similar to an offset), you can perform a count with a limit clause of 10,000 and use the next token to return the next 200 items with select."

So I'm trying to work out how to perform these two operations.  I start by getting a count of number of records (about 160 in my example), which I then subtract 20 from to create the offset.  But AWS is still returning the first 100 records.  I presume the code between "//++" isn't correct in creating the offset.

```
            //++ AWS has display limit of 100 so create offset by starting from count - 20 
        NSString *sdbAppOffset = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select count(*) from %@ limit %i",sdbAppUse,iDbaseRecordCountOffset];

        SimpleDBSelectRequest *selectOffsetRequest = [[SimpleDBSelectRequest alloc] initWithSelectExpression:sdbAppOffset];
        selectOffsetRequest.consistentRead = YES;

        SimpleDBSelectResponse *selectOffSetResponse = [sdbClient select:selectOffsetRequest];
        //NSLog(@"sdbAppUse count %i",[selectOffSetResponse.items count]);

        //++ 

        NSString *sdbAppUseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@",sdbAppUse];

        SimpleDBSelectRequest *selectRequest = [[SimpleDBSelectRequest alloc] initWithSelectExpression:sdbAppUseString];
        selectRequest.consistentRead = YES;

        SimpleDBSelectResponse *selectResponse = [sdbClient select:selectRequest];
        NSLog(@"sdbAppUse count %i",[selectResponse.items count]);

        for (int x = 0; x < [selectResponse.items count]; x++) { 

            SimpleDBItem *registerUser = [selectResponse.items objectAtIndex:x];

            for (SimpleDBAttribute *attribute in registerUser.attributes) {
                NSLog(@"trackUsage registerUser |%@|, name |%@|, value |%@|",registerUser.name, attribute.name, attribute.value);

            }
        }
```